# Use audio output USB device

Tags: audio, kubuntu, usb-audio

I have a Roland TD-30 drum connected using USB to my computer. The USB device support MIDI and audio input/output. Currently Linux does see the USB card. `aplay -l` shows:

```
  kaart 2: TD30 [TD-30], apparaat 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Sub-apparaten: 1/1
  Sub-apparaat #0: subdevice #0
```

When I call `cat /proc/asound/card2/*`, it shows me:

```
TD30
TD-30

Output 0
  Tx bytes     : 0
Input 0
  Rx bytes     : 0
cat: /proc/asound/card2/pcm0c: Is een map
cat: /proc/asound/card2/pcm0p: Is een map
Roland TD-30 at usb-0000:00:14.0-10, full speed : USB Audio

Playback:
  Status: Running
    Interface = 0
    Altset = 1
    Packet Size = 320
    Momentary freq = 44100 Hz (0x2c.199a)
  Interface 0
    Altset 1
    Format: S24_3LE
    Channels: 2
    Endpoint: 1 OUT (ADAPTIVE)
    Rates: 44100

Capture:
  Status: Running
    Interface = 1
    Altset = 1
    Packet Size = 320
    Momentary freq = 44100 Hz (0x2c.199a)
  Interface 1
    Altset 1
    Format: S24_3LE
    Channels: 2
    Endpoint: 2 IN (ASYNC)
    Rates: 44100
003/017
0582:0158
```

The midi input/output is working fine, but the audio input/output is not working at all. Alsamixer can only use the midi input/output.

Does someone know I can fix this? I'm using Kubuntu 18.10.

I got sound out of my usb device by booting Kubuntu with the audio device ON and plugged. Just after boot it works fine, but after a few minutes it stops and a reboot is needed. Can this be solved?

Comment: Your `cat` output shows working ALSA audio input/output. Next step would be to troubleshoot by describing what actually happens: there's a difference between "not working at all" and "after a few minutes it stops", you didn't describe what you used to test it (aplay? Something else?), you didn't say if Pulseaudio is running, etc., and given when the question was asked, you probably won't update it. It *could* be a bug in the TD30 driver, it also could be something else.

Comment: I use the default audio system in Kubuntu 19.04 (PulseAudio is installed).

Comment: So the first step is to take PulseAudio out of the picture, and see if you still have the same problem: Use `pulseaudio --kill`, verify with `ps axu | grep pulse` before and after that Pulseaudio is gone (if not, possibly you need to tweak something in Kubunutu: I don't use Kubuntu), then use `aplay -L | grep hw` to find the "hardware" ALSA device, and `aplay -D hw:... some_file.wav` to test it.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried hooking up my new TD-07 via USB. I could see it in aplay, but not in the mixer apps. The fix was to change the USB driver in the mixer from GENERIC to VENDOR. Not sure if that is an option on your situation.